# How can I match all properties to match the right guitar?

Tags: java

This code is from the headfirst book and it is ok no error with that

```
public Guitar search(Guitar searchGuitar) {
        for(Iterator i = guitars.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Guitar guitar = (Guitar)i.next();
            String builder = searchGuitar.getBuilder().toLowerCase();
            if((builder != null) && (!builder.equals("")) && (!builder.equals(guitar.getBuilder().toLowerCase()))){
                continue;
            }
            String model = searchGuitar.getModel().toLowerCase();
            if((model != null) && (!model.equals("") && (!model.equals(guitar.getModel().toLowerCase())))){
                continue;
            }
            String type = searchGuitar.getType().toLowerCase();
            if((type != null) && (!type.equals("")) && (!type.equals(guitar.getType().toLowerCase()))) {
                continue;
            }
            String backWood = searchGuitar.getBackWood().toLowerCase();
            if((backWood != null) && (!backWood.equals("")) && (!backWood.equals(guitar.getBackWood().toLowerCase()))) {
                continue;
            }
            String topWood = searchGuitar.getTopWood().toLowerCase();
            if((topWood != null) && (!topWood.equals("")) && (!topWood.equals(guitar.getTopWood().toLowerCase()))) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

but I don't understand why he typed that (!) if he wanted to return a guitar in inventory

```
(!builder.equals(guitar.getBuilder().toLowerCase()))
(!model.equals(guitar.getModel().toLowerCase()))
(!type.equals(guitar.getType().toLowerCase()))
(!backWood.equals(guitar.getBackWood().toLowerCase()))
(!topWood.equals(guitar.getTopWood().toLowerCase()))
```

that makes no sense if he wanted to match all the properties to match the guitar I think he should delete (!) and replace previous text with that

```
(builder.equals(guitar.getBuilder().toLowerCase()))
(model.equals(guitar.getModel().toLowerCase()))
(type.equals(guitar.getType().toLowerCase()))
(backWood.equals(guitar.getBackWood().toLowerCase()))
(topWood.equals(guitar.getTopWood().toLowerCase()))
```

that is more sense to me, can any one explain this to me ?

Comment: I can't believe this code is from that book because it is really bad. Bad in the sense that it has logic errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets just consider one part of it

```java
if((builder != null) && (!builder.equals("")) && (!builder.equals(guitar.getBuilder().toLowerCase()))){
    continue;
}
String model = searchGuitar.getModel().toLowerCase();
```

Basically it is saying if the builder of `searchGuitar` is not equal to that of the guitar of current iteration, it should `continue`(**i.e skip to the next iteration**), thus skipping all the code below the `if` block. In case if it is a match then it will not enter the `if` block and wont skip to next iteration, thus will get the `model` of the current iteration guitar (*code right below the `if` block*) to compare it in the next `if` block.

In short this code will skip to the next guitar if any of its property not match with the `searchGuitar`, and will only reach the end of a particular iteration if all the properties matches, which is exactly what we want.

#### Note:

This function will always return `null` as it does not return guitar if all properties matches and it reaches at the end of a iteration inside `for` loop. Thus it will always go through all iteration and exit the loop to return `null`. It should `return Guitar` if it reaches the end of a particular iteration (i.e all the properties matches with that of `searchGuitar`).